# Count Rows if value is between -364 and -182

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return the count of all the rows that have a specific value in order to take that count and divide it by the total count and get a percentage.

```
Select WORK_ORDER.BASE_ID As ID,
WORK_ORDER.STATUS As STATUS,
WORK_ORDER.PART_ID As PART_ID,
PART.DESCRIPTION As [DESC],
Ceiling(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_QTY) As ORD_QTY,
Ceiling(WORK_ORDER.RECEIVED_QTY) As QTY_DONE,
WORK_ORDER.WAREHOUSE_ID As WHS_ID,
WORK_ORDER.WBS_CODE As WBS_CODE,
WORK_ORDER.ENGINEERED_BY As ENG_BY,
Convert(CHAR(10),WORK_ORDER.SCHED_START_DATE,120) As SCHD_START,
Convert(CHAR(10),WORK_ORDER.SCHED_FINISH_DATE,120) As SCHD_FINISH,
Convert(CHAR(10),WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_RLS_DATE,120) As RLS_DATE,
Convert(CHAR(10),WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,120) As WANT_DATE,
DateDiff(day, GetDate(), IsNull(IsNull(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)) As DAYS_LATE,
IIF(DateDiff(day, GetDate(), IsNull(IsNull(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)) <= -365, -365,
IIF(DateDiff(day, GetDate(), IsNull(IsNull(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)) >= -364 And
DateDiff(day, GetDate(), IsNull(IsNull(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)) <= -182, -182,
IIF(DateDiff(day, GetDate(), IsNull(IsNull(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)) >= -181 And
DateDiff(day, GetDate(), IsNull(IsNull(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)) <= -91, -91,
IIF(DateDiff(day, GetDate(), IsNull(IsNull(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)) >= -90
And DateDiff(day, GetDate(), IsNull(IsNull(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)) <= -1,
-1, IIF(DateDiff(day, GetDate(), IsNull(IsNull(WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,
WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE)) >= 0, 0,
0))))) As Late_Group_By,
From WORK_ORDER
Inner Join PART On PART.ID = WORK_ORDER.PART_ID
Where WORK_ORDER.STATUS In ('F', 'R') And
Convert(CHAR(10),WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE,120) Is Not Null
Order By DAYS_LATE,
ID
```

[image: Output]

So for example if there are 10 rows with a Days_Late value that is between -90 and -1 I would want to know that and return that there's 10 rows that fall in this criteria and their percentage using 10/total rows *100.

Comment: `AND CONVERT(char(10), WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE, 120) IS NOT NULL` Why? Why not just `WORK_ORDER.DESIRED_WANT_DATE IS NOT NULL`? Also, I really recommend making *good* use of whitespace and line breaks; that SQL is very difficult to read

Comment: Presumably you want a (conditional) `COUNT`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` expressions inside count, and use `over ()` to bypass `group by` requirements. Your query is difficult to read, but based on your image and question, the line you are looking for is probably:

```
(count(case when days_late between [val1] and [val2] then 1 end) over () / (count(*) over () * 1.00)) * 100
```

You would substitute `[val1]` and `[val2]` for whatever range you wanted. This method using `over ()` will also duplicate on all of your rows, but we don't know your expected results so for now I will assume that is fine.

Comment: This isn't doing what you think it is. Counting `ID` just counts the number of non-nulls, not the number of distinct values. Instead you can just count `CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END`